# SQL Sum and Group by changing value of group

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

How do I group values ​​and change one of them when there is more than one

```
Table
ID | VALUE | NAME
1  |   2   | John
1  |   5   | Carl
2  |   4   | Elis
2  |   1   | Ted
3  |   2   | James


RESULT

ID | VALUE | NAME
1  |   7   |  *
2  |   5   |  *
3  |   2   | James
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way that should work in any database:

```
select id, sum(value) as value,
       (case when min(name) = max(name) then min(name) else '*' end) as name
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the others query you must try

```
Select ID, sum(Value) Value, NAME = ( Select b.Name + ' ' AS [text()]
            From dbo.test b
            Where a.ID = b.ID
            ORDER BY a.ID
            For XML PATH (''))
from test a
group by ID
order by ID
```